# Revkit make.py bootstrap error

Tags: make, tar, debootstrap

```
username@ubuntu:~$ cd revkit-2.2
username@ubuntu:~/revkit-2.2$ ./make.py bootstrap
bash: ./make.py: No such file or directory
```

What does this mean and why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

This means that there is no file named `make.py` within the `revkit-2.2` directory.

These are the files and directories contained within `revkit-2.2`:

```
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 8 norman norman 4096 Dec 22 05:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 norman norman 4096 Feb 26 21:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 norman norman 4096 Dec 22 05:28 addons
-rw-r--r-- 1 norman norman 2740 Dec 22 05:28 CMakeLists.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 norman norman 4096 Dec 22 05:28 ext
drwxr-xr-x 4 norman norman 4096 Dec 22 05:28 gui
drwxr-xr-x 4 norman norman 4096 Dec 22 05:28 programs
-rw-r--r-- 1 norman norman  770 Dec 22 05:28 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 5 norman norman 4096 Dec 22 05:28 src
drwxr-xr-x 5 norman norman 4096 Dec 22 05:28 test
```

You should read the `README.md` file for instructions:

```
# RevKit

## Requirements

The following software is required in order to build RevKit

* git
* cmake (at least version 2.8.9)
* g++ or clang++ (with C++11 support)
* boost (at least version 1.48.0)
* GNU MP, and its C++ interface GMP++
* Qt5 (only for the GUI)

## Build RevKit

After cloning RevKit perform the following steps

    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake ..
    make

To build the GUI perform the following steps from the base directory

    cd gui
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake ..
    make

## Build RevKit Addons

The easiest way to enable addons is by typing `ccmake ..' in the build directory

## Executing RevKit Programs

Executables can be found in the directory `build/programs'. Form the build
directory call e.g. `programs/circuit_info'
```

If you have any other issues, please do edit your question / comment! :)